# Холодные, как лёд, пальцы; сравн. оборот

Tags: запятые, сравнительный-оборот

Как выделяется "как лёд" в этом предложении: 
«Когда он поднёс ко мне свои холодные(,) как лёд(,) пальцы, я с трудом подавил в себе желание отпрянуть».

По сути, "как лёд" это же вставная часть, без которой смысл, в принципе, не меняется, но я часто вижу, что в случаях, как в этом предложении, многие почему-то не выделяют такой сравнительный оборот. И тут вопрос: а нужно ли вообще? Помогите разобраться!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Когда он поднёс ко мне свои холодные, **как лёд,** пальцы, я с трудом подавил в себе желание отпрянуть.*

Итак, в этом предложении мы  обособляем сравнительный оборот как лед. **Но как же, ведь это же устойчивый оборот, в списке у Розенталя значится!** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Но там же у Розенталя вот что еще значится:

Вопрос о пунктуации при сравнительных оборотах, **в частности при сравнениях идиоматического (фразеологического) характера,** не может решаться в отрыве от характера самих оборотов (сравнения общеязыкового типа или художественные сравнения, иногда индивидуально-авторские), состава устойчивых сочетаний, как он представлен в толковых и фразеологических словарях русского языка, и т. д.

В общем, говорит Розенталь **об индивидуальном подходе** при обособлении сравнительных оборотов, вот и попробуем провести анализ конкретного оборота в конкретном предложении.

1) Если взглянуть на список Розенталя, то можно увидеть, что большинство устойчивых оборотов относятся **к глаголам или кратким прилагательным**, которые в предложении являются сказуемыми. **Полных форм меньше** (твердый как камень, сладкий как мед и др.), при этом в текстах **они обычно обособляются, несмотря на устойчивость**.

**Почему?** Потому что в этом случае они выполняют **функцию уточняющего несогласованного определения,** которое **в такой позиции** обычно обособляется, например:

*Через минуту три истребителя один за другим поднялись в голубоватый, **как бы перламутровый**, воздух (Кат.); Он увидел на белой шапке кургана  рдяно-жёлтую, **с огнистым отливом**, лису (Ш.); Гаврик со всех сторон осмотрел маленького гимназиста в длинной, **до пят,** шинели (Кат.);*

При этом **интонационно такие обороты никак не выделяются** (для этого нет возможности), поэтому обособление их делается только **по грамматическому принципу.**

2) Если сравнительный оборот относится **к именному сказуемому**, то он может обособляться или не обособляться, например:

(1) *Плечи Александры были **холодны как лЁд**, когда он снова обнял ее, чтобы вести к дому.*

Это СПП, в главном предложении **обособлять оборот неудобно**, ударение там падает только на конец фразы.

*Она послушно протянула руки, которые были **холоднЫ, как лЁд.** Белла **холоднА, как лЁд,** она никого не любит, кроме ― не себя даже, ― а производимого ею впечатления.*

В этих предложениях смысловое **ударение падает на прилагательное**, оборот является попутным сравнением.

Answer (score 1):

Есть сравнительные обороты, а есть устойчивые выражения, фразеологизмы вроде "красный как рак", "белый как сметь", "здоров как бык" и др. "Холодный как лёд" относится сюда же. Запятая не нужна. Не все авторы в курсе этого, оттуда и появляется иногда запятая.

Comment: Таких авторов много, например: " Я обернулся. Он смотрел холодными, как лед, глазами".  [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором... (2009)]  Существуют обе формы письма для сравнительного оборота "как лед",  решение зависит от конкретного предложения.

Comment: Я бы не ссылался на популярность того или иного решения, как на аргумент, иначе пришлось бы считаться с "одеть шапку", "от слова совсем" и "такой себе". Да, возможны варианты с запятой и без, но там всегда есть место для дискуссии. Как по мне, в качестве универсального решения допустимо считать "холодный как лёд" фразеологизмом и не ставить запятую. А вот ставить её всюду — не то.

Comment: Я ссылаюсь на приличных авторов в Нацкорпусе, почему-то они не использовали универсальное решение. В то же время их книги проверяют корректоры и редакторы, это вполне осмысленный выбор. Примеры: Она послушно протянула руки, которые были холодны, как лед. [Анатолий Приставкин (2005)] Белла холодна, как лед, она никого не любит, кроме ― не себя даже, ― а производимого ею впечатления.  [Ю. М. Нагибин. Дневник (1972)]  Но есть примеры без обособления. Плечи Александры были холодны как лед, когда он снова обнял ее, чтобы вести к дому.  [Александр Пятигорский.  2001]. В каждом случае нужен анализ.

Comment: При всём уважении, корректоры и редакторы делают свою работу из рук вон плохо. Всюду ошибки. Ссылаться на современные книги, как на источник грамотной письменной речи, решение так себе. Есть справочники с правилами — другое дело. В Вашем случае было бы справедливо дать свой ответ с объяснением нюансов, когда запятую ставить, когда нет. Будет убедительно — сам за Ваш ответ проголосую. Но аргументация "так в книге напечатано" не катит, извините. У меня, скажем,  есть книга, где выражения вроде "также как" встречаются. Тоже и редактор был, и корректор. Толку то.

Comment: Я же не отвечаю, а просто комментирую Ваш ответ.( Как говорили латиняне, чтобы рассказать, а не доказать). Я и рассказываю, что частотность обособленных и необособленных оборотов в Нацкорпусе примерно равная. из чего можно сделать вывод, что не все фразеологизмы всегда обособляются. Вы же об этом говорили в своем ответе.

Comment: @Sharon я Вас понял

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, это еще не стало устойчивым выражением того уровня, когда обособление очевидно не требуется. Так что тут лучше запятые сохранить.
Впрочем, все - на волю автора.

Comment: Кстати, выражение " холодный как лед" значится в списке Розенталя. Приводим перечень наиболее распространенных устойчивых сочетаний с союзом как (по данным словарей и по наблюдениям над текстами разных жанров) :http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147 И вот интересно, как школьная педагогика решает такие задачи? В принципе ученик тоже может сослаться на право авторского решения.

Comment: @Sharon Ну, значит, я не прав. ))) *...Как школьная педагогика решает такие задачи?* - да никак не решает. Не буду цитировать, дабы не захламлять, просто ссылку дам. Почитайте, любопытное отношение. Это пишет человек не одну собаку съевший на школьной тематике. http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6842&start=40#p485128 - отсюда и ниже.

Comment: Я к устойчивым оборотам отношусь так: устойчивый оборот  чаще, чем другие сравнения,  ставится в позицию наречия и не обособляется, но это не значит, что не обособляется никогда. Поэтому я не считаю, что Вы не правы. Спасибо за ссылку. К сожалению, форумные записи читать очень сложно, я их с трудом понимаю. И, как мне кажется, там очень много эмоций, едва ли не больше, чем смысла.